# hello.js, get access token (or anything at all)

Tags: javascript, facebook, oauth, hello.js

I'm trying to use [hello.js](http://adodson.com/hello.js) to allow users to login using their social media accounts.  I seem to be successfully getting the allow page to show, and a redirect is happening but I don't understand how my system is supposed to know who that person is.  I'm assuming it's via the access token but I can't seem to print it to the console at any point of the login process.

```
$('#facebookLogin').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    hello('facebook').login({display:'page'});
    return false;
});
```

This "works" as in, I see the app connected in my Facebook apps.  I've tried to follow the instructions [here](http://www.nealbohling.com/2014/05/using_hello/) in order to show the object after login but I see nothing with `console.log(token)`.

```
$('#facebookLogin').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    hello( 'facebook' ).login({display: 'page'} function() {
       var token = hello( 'facebook' ).getAuthResponse().access_token;
       console.log(token);
    });
    return false;
});
```

I humbly request that if you have answer to post working code.  There's a lot of text trying to explain this and I really don't understand it.  I need to see something that works.

Comment: http://adodson.com/hello.js/demos/profile.html#helloapi-me-

Comment: I've edited the code in that link to simple log to the console and I get absolutely nothing.  hello.on('auth.login', function(r){

 hello( r.network ).api( '/me' ).then( function(p){
  console.log(r);
  console.log(p);
 });
});

Comment: I've also tried it with alert(p); alert(r); and it doesn't alert once.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```
$('#facebookLogin').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    hello('facebook').login({display: 'page'},
    function() {
        hello('facebook').api("me")
                .then(function(userDetails) {
                    console.log("hello api success");
                    console.log(userDetails);
                }, function(e) {
                    console.log(e);
                });
    });

    return false;

});
```

`userDetails` contains user credentials.

Hope it helps.